# .Net Regular Expression Crashes aspnet_wp.exe

Tags: .net, regex

I'm having the following problem and wondered whether anyone could see why this is crashing my .net worker process (aspnet_wp.exe):

```
  Dim pattern As String = "\{\{IF\(((?!\)}})(.))+,,,((\s)*(?!\)}})(.))+\)}}"
  Dim mc As RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(txtContent.Text, pattern)
```

Works absolutely fine if a match is found, e.g

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>Top paragraph.</p>

{{IF(1=2,,, <p></p>)}}
```

But if no match is found it seems to nail my cpu and run for quite a while, e.g if the last bracket is missing before the final two curly brakcets:

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>Top paragraph.</p>

{{IF(1=2,,, <p></p>}}
```

Is it too greedy that it searches forever!? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is easily identified: ["Catastrophic Backtracking"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Every time you see the "if a match exists, it works, if no match exists, it takes forever" phenomenon, you can be sure that's the cause.

I suggest a different regex that does less backtracking. [Atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) can help keeping backtracking steps at a minimum:

```
Dim pattern As String = "\{\{IF\((?>(?:(?!,,,).)+),,,(?>(?:(?!\)\}\}).)+)\}\}"
Dim mc As RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(txtContent.Text, pattern)
```

The pattern (don't know if I capture everything you need - add parentheses where you see fit):

```
\{\{IF\(                # "{{IF("
(?>(?:(?!,,,).)+)       # atomic group: any char up to the ",,,"
,,,                     # ",,,"
(?>(?:(?!\)\}\}).)+)    # atomic group: any char up to the ")}}"
\)\}\}                  # ")}}"
```